# Having trouble making a table of the derivative of a Bessel-function-based expression

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

Please suggest how I should correct the following code to plot the integral:

```
γ1 = 30*10^-3; ρ = 1*10^3; g = 9.8; A0 = 10^9;
c = 3*10^8; n1 = 1; n2 = 1.33;
P[we_] := ((4*4)/(c*Pi*we^2))*(n1)*((n2 - n1)/(n2 + n1));
u1 = γ1 * k^2 + ρ*g;
h[r_, we_] := A0*P[we]*we^2/4*Exp[-(we^2*k^2)/8]*k*BesselJ[0, (r)*k]/u1
CR2 = Evaluate[D[h[r, we], {r, 2}]]
κR[r_?NumericQ, we_?NumericQ] := Quiet[NIntegrate[CR2, {k, 0, ∞}]]
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[κR[r, we], {we, 30*10^-6, 80*10^-6, 50*10^-6}], 
  {r, -0.0005, .0005}, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plots of h and its derivative]

Comment: Define `CR2[r_, we_] = D[h[r, we], {r, 2}] `  and do `\[Kappa]R[r_?NumericQ, we_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[CR2[r, we], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 100] `

Comment: @Akku 14, Thanks, It is working, But If I want to plot h[r, we]  unwanted kink appeared (I updated code with figures).